# Why the div not take full width or 100% width?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make a table and chart. When I show both together, both will take 100% width. Please check in full screen. But when I apply `ng-show` condition the chart is not show in 100% width why? It is show only 50 to 60% of width.

- Please check on full screen and click on show chart button..then it will display only 50% width ..it should me in 100 %..

Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/lXM2UbYUeT8NSkDeYCgb?p=preview

```
$scope.isshowTable = true;
$scope.showChart = function() {
    $scope.isshowTable = false;
}
$scope.showTable = function() {
    $scope.isshowTable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your chart directive style, width="100%", the chart will use the width by default.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HkAD1eyD1QGHIUyU7uml?p=preview

```
<chart value="basicAreaChart" type="area" height="400" style="width:100%"></chart>
```

Here is why, http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width

> width: Number An explicit width for the chart. By default the width is
>   calculated from the offset width of the containing element. Try it:
>
> 800px wide

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you initiated the chart at the beginning, and the $scope.showChart is just to determine the chart is shown or not.

Once the chart is initiated, it will base on the *current* width.

One of the solutions is to initiate the chart again upon $scope.showChart.

P.S.: The interesting is that if u change the width of the box while the chart is shown, it becomes 100% width again.  Probably because of the responsive css in the chart lib.